# How can I mark a line to always fail?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tslint

Is there a way to add a tslint directive to mark next line as error? This would be useful when testing with code that should not be committed, for example debug code or commented out functional lines.

```
// thisImportantFunction();
// tslint:error-next-line
myTestCodeFunction();
```

Comment: Maybe tslint is not the right tool for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like this is supported out-of-the-box:

https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/rule-flags/

However, TSLint does support custom rules:

https://palantir.github.io/tslint/develop/custom-rules/

A potential solution would be to write a custom rule that always fails, disable it for the project, and then enable above lines you want to always fail:

```
/* tslint:enable:error-next-line */
myTestCodeFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the line in question to this:

```
debugger;
```

It should be caught by the linter and does not affect the code except if you are running the developer tools.

**Update**

Or you can create an unassigned variable or an assignment in an `if`:

```
if (let a = 10) {
  a = 20;
}
```

Again, your linter should not allow that to stay, but it will not harm your code.

Comment: Correct. But most cases I would be running with devtools playing with live page, don't want to have to continue each time. Looking for a more generic solution.